# create minumum delay of 50ms java android with multi threads

Tags: java, android

How can I force that threads run on different cores multi threads ?
I have real time audio and record code on java android.
I have one thread for record and other thread for play.
My goal is play input with delay. I need delay of ~50ms. I use nexus 4/5

Comment: "How can I force that threads run on different cores multi threads ?" -- you don't. That is not your responsibility. That is up to the OS developers and the device manufacturer. The decision of how many cores to use will be based on many things, spanning the entire device, not just your app.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //run whatever task you're running
    }
}, 0, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The above code will wait to run the thread after 50 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think, using Handler you can slove this. Write your record code above the Handler and write play code inside the Handler.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                },50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution if you need to repeat. It incorporate a Handler with a `postDelayed`.

Important: You need to remove any Callbacks!

Try something like this:

```
private boolean continueLoop = true;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

private void startAutoDownloadManager() {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "AutoDownloadManager - Started");
        // here the delay (in this example it is effectively the interval) is 1 second
        myHandler.postDelayed(mAutoDownloadManager, 50);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Runnable mAutoDownloadManager = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(continueLoop){
            // preform the scan
            startWhatEverMethodYouWish();

            //re-trigger the call to start the scan
            startAutoDownloadManager();
        {
    }
};

// Make certain that you remove the callback when you leave the activity -- maybe in onPause()
private void stopAutoDownloadManager(){
    try{
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(mAutoDownloadManager);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```